# Convert Word (.docx !) to html with Apache POI + fr.opensagres.xdocreport

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, docx, xdocreport

I could implement converting the old *.doc* files to *html* only with Apache POI.

**For** ***.docx***, however, I had to use the `fr.opensagres.xdocreport` package.
Code is pretty straightforward:

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create().indent(4).setImageManager(new Base64EmbedImgManager());
    XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, outputStream, options);
    return outputStream.toString();
```

However, there **two issues**:

- embedded excel charts are ignored (the *.doc* conversion with Apache POI converts them to images just like it does with any other normal image)
- text that has custom various format combinations is not rendered correctly, several new-lines are inserted unnecessarily. ( see [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUF9i.jpg) and [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07hH2.jpg) examples)

Does anybody know any way to fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: XDocReport are indeed some limitation, please report problem at https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/issues

Comment: Done. See issues #281 and #280 .